# Permutations with order condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've been thinking about a problem and I'm not sure if it's already been formally solved or if it's something unknown. Here is the problem:

> Suppose you have a list of elements: {A0,A1,B0,B1}
> How many permutations of the list exist given that each permutation must not contain a state where a lettered value of a given number precedes the same lettered value of a smaller number.
> Example:
> {A1,A0,B0,B1} is invalid because A1 > A0 and A1 precedes A0 in the list.
> {A0,B0,A1,B1} is valid because A1 follows A0 and B1 follows B0 in the list order.

Consider that this problem can easily scale to {A0-An,B0-Bn,...,Z0-Zn} to I would need some non-brute force way of solving this. I wrote a computer program that solves this with recursion, but the time complexity is huge which got me wondering if someone a lot of smarter than me has already thought of this and solved it.

Comment: Do you know how many permutations there are of the string $AABBCC$?

Comment: Yes, AABBCC is 6 choose 6, which is just 6! = 720. This wouldn't give an answer though, as some of the ABC values would not follow the order constraint.

Comment: Actually, the number of distinguishable ways of permuting the letters of the string $AABBCC$ is $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$.  Pick two of the six positions for the two $A$s, two of the remaining four positions for the two $B$s, and then fill both of the last two positions with the two $C$s.  There is a connection between this problem and the one you asked.

Comment: As a further explanation of the comment of @N.F.Taussig,consider the $12$ characters $A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3, C_1, C_2, C_3, D_1, D_2, D_3.$ Ignoring your constraint, these $12$ items can be permuted in $(12)!$ ways.  However, consider partitioning these $(12)!$ ways by how the $A_1, A_2, A_3$ elements are ordered.  These $3$ items can be ordered in $(3!)$ ways.  If you group them by how they are ordered, you will have partitioned the $(12)!$ ways into $(6)$ groups.  Further, $(5)$ of the $6$ groups will be violating the constraint that elements $A_1, A_2, A_3$ must occur in that order.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You're amazing, thank you so much. I think I understand the solution. Since I only want one variation (the one where the numbers are ascending), I can treat this like a combination and multiply the combinations as you demonstrated.